# Trends and numbers of searches made in Google Search

Tags: google-search

How you can see the trend of a specific sentence as searched on Google?

For example: How do I see the number of searches for "banana cake" on a monthly basis?

Does Google have some function which allows you to search for a sentence, and see how many times it has been searched for each month?

Answer (score 1):

You can enter your search on [Google Trends](http://www.google.com/trends/).  For example, [here is a graph](http://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=%22banana%20cake%22) showing the monthly search interest for "banana cake".

Note that the monthly numbers on the graph aren't the exact number of times that people searched for "banana cake".  Google explains this on a [support page](https://support.google.com/trends/answer/4355164?hl=en&ref_topic=4365531):

> The numbers on the graph reflect how many searches have been done for a particular term, relative to the total number of searches done on Google over time. They don't represent absolute search volume numbers, because the data is normalized and presented on a scale from 0-100. Each point on the graph is divided by the highest point and multiplied by 100. When we don't have enough data, 0 is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Google has a tool called "Keyword Planner", which is normally used to plan AdWords campaigns, but you can also use it to get an overview how often a certain word or phrase is being searched for.

https://adwords.google.com/ko/KeywordPlanner